# Is there a way to feed IIS logs into App Insights from Log analytics workspace?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics

We've logs(W3CIISLogs) on Log analytics workspace for websites hosted on VMs. Similarly we have app insights enabled for websites hosted on App service. Now we want to access telemetry data of both type of websites thru single interface, either via app insights or via Log analytics. Just wondering if it's possible and what's the best way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Azure Monitor you can now query not only across multiple Log Analytics workspaces, but also data from a specific Application Insights app in the same resource group, another resource group, or another subscription. This provides you with a system-wide view of your data. You can only perform these types of queries in [Log Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/log-query/portals).

Querying across Log Analytics workspaces and from Application Insights - reference another workspace in your query, use the [workspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/log-query/workspace-expression) identifier and for an app from Application Insights, use the [app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/log-query/app-expression) identifier.

Cross-resource query limits:

- The number of Application Insights resources that you can include in
  a single query is limited to 100.
- Cross-resource query is not supported in View Designer. You can Author a query in Log 
  Analytics and pin it to Azure dashboard and visualize a log search.
- Cross-resource query in log alerts is supported in the new
  scheduledQueryRules API. By default, Azure Monitor uses the legacy
  Log Analytics Alert API for creating new log alert rules from Azure
  portal, unless you switch from legacy Log Alerts API. After the
  switch, the new API becomes the default for new alert rules in Azure
  portal and it lets you create cross-resource query log alerts rules.
  You can create cross-resource query log alert rules without making
  the switch by using the ARM template for scheduledQueryRules API –
  but this alert rule is manageable though scheduledQueryRules API and
  not from Azure portal.

Documentation Reference - [Cross-Resource Log queries in Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/log-query/cross-workspace-query)

Hope the above information helps.